# how to set Dynamic image in webview from drawable folder

Tags: android, webview

I am new to android in my application i wants to set dynamic text & image in webview. Dynamic text is done but problem in getting image from resource folder. which i wants to set right top corner in Webview.
here my code

```
ImgName = "a" + pro_id + "_th";
int res = this.getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.app:drawable/" + ImgName,null, null);


webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activityDDetail_Discription_webView);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
String disc = Model.get_discription();

String html1 = "<div style=\"text-align: justify; margin: 10px 0px;\"><div style=\"float: right; margin: 0px 3px 1px 10px;\"><font color = \"ffffff\" face = \"HelveticaNeue-Light\" size = \"3.0\">"+ discription()+ "</font></span> </div>";

webView.loadData(html1, "text/html", "UTF-8");
html1 = String.format(html1, ImgName);
final String mime = "text/html";
final String encoding = "UTF-8";
```

Comment: What u getting as error or output?

Comment: not getting any error but image is not visible in webview

Answer (score 0):

i am using this,

```
Using the resource id, the format is:

    "android.resource://[package]/[res id]"

    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.androidbook.samplevideo/" + R.raw.myvideo);
or, using the resource sub directory (type) and resource name (file name without extension), the format is:

    "android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]"

    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.androidbook.samplevideo/raw/myvideo")
```